# Building an amplifier out of diodes

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, diodes

It is quite obvious that we can't build an amplifier out of resistors (because of their linearity). But is there a circuit theorem that states the impossibility of building an amplifier out of diodes (semiconductor or vacuum tube ones) without using transistors, relays and other 3-terminal devices?

Comment: I guess a phototransistor is a kind of two-terminal amplifier.

Comment: There's conservation of energy. Without some power source other than the input signal, you'll never get power amplification. If you consider diodes with a negative resistance region (like tunnel diodes) you can make an amplifier circuit from them.

Comment: @the-photon Of course, such a hypothetical "diode-only amplifier" will also have a power supply lines - just as all existing amplifiers do. So is it possible to construct such a device?

Comment: Yes, a **Parametric Amplifier** uses a diode as a gain element, in concert with LC passives. However, it must be pumped by an AC source, which would require a power supply, and some kind of amplifying device. Just as @ThePhoton says.

Comment: The most fun type of amplifier I know of is a magnetic amplifier, as it uses only a transformer. However, it's a special type of transformer, designed to saturate, and it requires a pump signal. It's very robust, and was often used as a power output stage to drive servo motors for WW2 gunnery platforms. Go [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_amplifier)

Comment: @Neil_UK Mag amps are also popular in the nuclear power game where they are sometimes used for control rod drivers, the attraction presumably being the reliability and relative ease of writing a safety case (Having a failed power device be able to drive a control rod fully out of the core is not a popular design in that space), resolvers and mag amps are nice like that.

Comment: a 2 pin semiconductor device with a negative incremental resistance ( resistance lowers with rise of input) may amplify current drawn from the supply above some threshold  to amplify power out somehow but the resulting specs would be very nonlinear and must be filtered for some limited application.

Answer (score 8):

Gunn diodes have a region of negative resistance, i.e., at certain input voltage the current flowing through the diode is increased when the voltage is decreased. These diodes can be used to amplify RF, but they only become practical at microwave frequencies.

[Wikipedia: Gunn diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunn_diode)

https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/diode/gunn-microwave-diode.php

Answer (score 4):

You can make an amplifier from tunnel diodes, but that's probably not what you are talking about, since ordinary diodes do not exhibit a negative resistance characteristic, at least not in the normal range of operation.

It's possible to make a [parametric amplifier](http://www.tuks.nl/pdf/Reference_Material/Parametric_Excitation/Blackwell%20-%20Semiconductor-Diode%20Parametric%20Amplifiers%20-1961.pdf) from an ordinary diode because of the capacitance change with voltage. That involves a pump oscillator at a higher frequency than the signal you want to amplify. It has been used for very high frequencies and more moderate ones (eg.  Philbrick P2 amplifier).

However, this is an incomplete answer without some kind of reference to a theorem that says the resistive nonlinearity of a diode cannot possibly provide voltage or current gain.

Comment: given the gm of a diode is 0.026ma/volt at 1mA, and 1amp/volt at 26mA, can that be used. Still no power gain, of course.